# React get state cannot map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a table from this.state.line[0].map. However, I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error. I try to console.log on line 54 (inside set state arrow function)it did display an array. Inside the productlist function, I added if the array is undefined, is should skip it but when is not undefined, is should return the table items but is not working.

```
const temp = {}
const ref = React.createRef();
export default class Inbound_scan extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    var state = { line: [] }
    this.state = state
    this.onKeyUp = this.onKeyUp.bind(this);
  }

  onKeyUp(e) {
    const line2 = { line: [] }

    if (e.key == "Enter") {
      const carton_id = document.getElementById('carton_id').value
      const sku = document.getElementById('sku').value

      let line = temp;
      
      if (!line.hasOwnProperty(sku)) {
        line[sku] = 0
      }
      
      line[sku] = line[sku] + 1
      const fomrated = Object.entries(line).map(([sku, qty]) => ({ sku, qty }))

      this.setState({ line: [] })
      line2.line.push(fomrated)
      
      console.log("62")
      console.log(line2.line[0])

      this.setState({ line: [line2.line[0]] }, () => {
        console.log(this.state)
        this.product_list();
        console.log(this.state.line[0])
      });
      document.getElementById('sku').value = ''
    }
  }

  product_list() {
    if (typeof (this.state.line[0]) != 'undefined') {
      this.state.line[0].map((item, index) => {
        return <tr> <th scope="row">{index}</th><td>{item.sku}</td><td>{item.sku}</td></tr>
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
              <Form.Control placeholder="Carton" name="carton_id" id="carton_id" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" onKeyPress={this.onKeyUp} >
              <Form.Control placeholder="SKU" name="sku" id="sku" />
            </Form.Group>
            {/* <Form.Group className="mb-3"   >
                            <Form.Control placeholder="Quantity" name="qty" id="qty" type="number" />
                        </Form.Group> */}
            <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={this.onKeyUp}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">SKU</th>
                <th scope="col">QTY</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                this.product_list()}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </Container>
      </div >
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you're using React you probably shouldn't be using native DOM methods like `getElementById`.

Comment: Also "temp" is always the same object, which is generally a bad idea for state. I find it difficult to reason about this code--it's tricky to figure out what's happening vs what *should* be happening.

Comment: try binding `product_list()` function as well in constructor. as you are trying to access `this.state` inside `product_list()`